# Adding Custom Field in BigCommerce Theme

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce, theming, cornerstone

Is it possible to add a custom field to output custom content to the Footer template? Apologies if this has been asked already...

I'm looking to add a custom field in the admin area so that some custom content can be output dynamically in the footer template rather than being hardcoded. Is this possible? I am currently using the Cornerstone Light theme.

If so, can someone point me in the right direction as to how I add the Custom Field in the Admin and then output that value in the footer.html template file.

Thanks in advance for any help on this...

Answer (score 2):

To provide merchants with Design (Admin) support for your theme's settings (custom fields), you must declare those settings in the theme's schema.json file. You must also include those settings in your theme's config.json file, templates, and Sass/CSS files.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/store-design/schema-json-metadata

Comment: Great stuff thanks for the response, I'll give this a go. I tried something similar but any values I entered into the custom field didn't save.